Unable to add jobs to Bus Batch in Laravel
I am unable to add jobs to Bus Batch in Laravel in a foreach loop, and get the error Call to undefined method App\Jobs\ProcessSitemapChunk::withBatchId().
        $sitemapUrl = 'someurl';
        $urls = $this->extractUrlsFromSitemap($sitemapUrl);

        $chunkSize = 50; // Number of URLs per chunk
        $chunks = array_chunk($urls, $chunkSize); // chunk working well.
         
        $batch = Bus::batch([])->name('Process Sitemap')->dispatch();

        foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
            $batch->add(new ProcessSitemapChunk($chunk));
        }



I tried to add these traits.
use Illuminate\Bus\Batchable;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;

but no success please help.

My Mistake I didn't add
use Illuminate\Bus\Batchable;

in ProcessSitemapChunk Job.
Problem Solved.
